# Emit to a socket upon server reload

Tags: node.js, express, http, websocket, socket.io

So, I want socket.io to emit to my client on server reload. I am using express, http, and socket.io. I want to emit a message to the client when my server reloads saying that they should reload their page. Below is what I have currently. When the server starts, it will emit to the client.

```
http.listen(3000, () => {
  io.emit('server-update')
})
```

That is all I have so far. That doesn't work though. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: I think we need more info... I was considering answering, but I realized I'm making too many assumptions about what you're trying to do. Please explain further, including details on your environment. Are you talking about hot reloading using a tool - what tool? What does it mean when you say it doesn't work - is there an error message? etc.

Comment: No, there is no error message. Here is more detailed code. My bad :) I just want to emit a socket.io call to the client from the Node.js server. There is no error message, it just doesn't emit.

Comment: In my client side I have socket.on('server-update', () => {// Code}). The code doesn't seem to emit once I restart the server. I just want it to emit a message to the client that the server has been reloaded so for best performance, they should reload their browswr.

Comment: It's best to edit your question to make it clearer. My guess is that there's a "re-connect" step missing - the server goes down, the client connection is closed/lost, the server comes back up and emits to a non-existent connection. You probably need to reconnect; maybe consider emitting when the server goes down, not when it comes up.

Comment: Oh! That's a great idea! How would I go about doing that? I am still relatively new to Node.js, my apologies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out! I appreciate all of your help! Here's what I came up with:

```
http.listen(3000, () => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    io.emit('server-update')  
  }, 1000)
})
```

It helps to wait for a user connection :)